# SQL join with 2 conditions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Let's say we have a table "pages" with records

```
|ID    | Name |
|1     | Test1|
|2     | Test2|
```

and "categories":

```
|PAGE_ID| ID | NAME  |
|1      |  1 | Nice  | 
|1      |  2 | Supper|
|2      |  3 | Nice  |
```

I need to get all pages that belongs to category "Nice" **AND** "Supper" 
in this case we have 1 page => Test1.

Can this be done in 1 SELECT with 1 join, or subselect or second join is needed?
The best would be to get a result like

```
|PAGE_ID | PAGE.NAME| CATEGORY.NAME_1 | CATEGORY.NAME_2
```

and then just pick up the right record with a simple where.

Comment: What is desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    c1.page_id, p.name, c1.name, c2.name
from
    pages p
    inner join
    categories c1 on p.id = c1.page_id
    inner join
    categories c2 on p.id = c2.page_id
where
    c1.name = 'Nice' and c2.name = 'Supper'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT p.ID page_id, p.Name page_name, 'Nice' Category1, 'Supper' Category2
  FROM categories c LEFT JOIN
       pages p ON c.PAGE_ID = p.ID
WHERE c.Name IN ('Nice', 'Supper')
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Name
HAVING COUNT(p.ID) = 2
```

Output:

```
| PAGE_ID | PAGE_NAME | CATEGORY1 | CATEGORY2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|       1 |     Test1 |      Nice |    Supper |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/73cf9/9)**

*This solution works fine when you need to find pages more than in two categories without continuously chaining `JOIN`s.*